# Scan for three same BLE sensors with same CBUUID but different MAC address by iPhone Device

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, cbperipheral, cbcentralmanager

I have 3 sensors with same `CBUUID`, i.e. all three sensors transmit the same type of services but have different MAC address.

In forground scanning things are fine I can use `CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey = YES` to get different delegate callbacks for same CBUUID by different BLE device. But in **background scanning** of peripherals `CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey` is ignored. How will I scan these 3 sensors in the background because all packets will be coalesced into one and advertised as one packet by iOS.

[This link talks about only foreground scanning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26720630/how-do-you-scan-for-the-same-ble-device-twice)

Answer (score 2):

The `allowDuplicates` option means that you app will receive multiple callbacks to the `didDiscover` delegate method *for the same peripheral*.

It is not required simply to discover multiple peripherals that are advertising the *same service*.

When you start scanning you should specify the `CBUUID` of the *service* you are interested in. Once you get a call to `didDiscover` you can store the peripheral's `identifier` and use that to connect to the peripheral in the future.

Scanning for a specific service works in both the foreground and background.

Comment: So you mean that for all "n" peripherals advertising the same kind of service, regardless of  `CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey = NO / YES`, I will get "n" callbacks in -didDiscoverPeripheral?

Comment: Correct.   Each time a new peripheral advertising the nominated service(s) is discovered you will get a call back.  A duplicate is  call back for an already discovered peripheral, not an already discovered service type

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll do some more POC on this.